# .htaccess redirect to /pages unless index

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes, altorouter

I'm using a PHP router (AltoRouter) that allows me to define routes in all sorts of manners but doesn't do any kind of redirecting.

I want my '/' route to remain as is.

But if someone goes to anything other than '/' I have a wildcard route that grabs the name of that route, locates a twig file, and renders it based on name. So '/about' would locate `about.twig` and render it.

What I want to achieve is if someone goes to '/about' or '/contact', etc, then they'd be re-routed to '/pages/about', '/pages/contact', etc, but if they go to '/pages/about' directly then no re-route necessary.

My current .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately I did a bunch of searching around and didn't really find how to do that specific conditional re-route/redirect. Especially not one that left the root '/' alone.

P.s. `pages` isn't actually a directory on the server. I just want to insert 'pages' before the page name.

Comment: That would be very basic rules each: `RewriteRule ^contact$ /pages/contact [R,L]` - unless there's something more complex going on with your front controller.

Comment: So you want to append `/pages/` before everything or before some known strings?

Comment: @anubhava I want my URLs to look like http://example.com/pages/page-name.

Currently it is just http://example.com/page-name. But 'pages' isn't a directory in the project. I want to add it to the URL despite it not being an actual directory. All while not affecting the root '/' route.

Comment: @mario the routes aren't pre-defined like that. There's 200+ pages and if I were to add an htaccess entry for each one or a route for each one, my .htaccess would be massive. I need a wildcard type of redirect rule that grabs the page-name after '/' and rewrites it to '/pages/page-name'. However if someone types in '/pages/page-name' directly then no rewrite should occur. And 'pages' isn't an actual directory in the project. It's just a prefix to the page I want to add as if it were an actual directory.

Comment: At some point you're going to have to list the available pages `^(page-name|about|contact|...)$` because Apache can't read the PHP regexen itself. Of course a general `^(\w+)$` would allow to capture *any* pagename. As you probably know already. Else: [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](//stackoverflow.com/q/20563772)

Comment: You can use `RewriteMap` if you have access to Apache config.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this immediately after `RewriteEngine on`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/pages/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /pages/$1 [R,L]
```